# Tablespace issue with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am facing a problem.

I had postgresql 9.4.5 version running on my linux VM. I wanted to run an instance of postgresql 9.5 on it also.

I stopped the postgresql 9.4.5 service and started the service for postgres 9.5 with different data directory supplied in the service file.

Now when the postgres 9.5 is running , then when I connect to the database, I find that the postgres is picking up databases from the postgresql 9.4.5 tablespace location . Eg: a database userdata tablespace is present in folder called /TablespaceLocation , then on connecting to postgres 9.5 it shows this database when I run the \db command.

When I try to connect to this particular database then I get an error that data file for this data base is missing from the data storage location of postgres.

Now I want to seggregate the table space location of postgres 9.4.5 and postgres 9.5 . How is it picking the tablespace from postgres 9.4.5 tablespace location?

Comment: PostgreSQL will never do this by itself; there are version subdirectories in the tablespace directory that prevent PostgreSQL from seeing data from different versions. Moreover, you won't see a database in PostgreSQL unless there are metadata for the database in `pg_database`. So something is weird. Probably there are scripts in your installation that automatically performed an upgrade. Can you still use your 9.4.5 installation to see the database? Can you provide more details about your problem, like what *exactly* you do and what error messages you get?

Comment: Yes I am able to connect to the postgresql 9.4.5. There wasn't any upgradation scripts running. The problem I guess could have been that in the tablespace location folder pg_tblspc of 9.5, there was symbolic link created to another location which was used for tablespace storage for 9.4.5 . So I guess that is why I am seeing the database but not able to connect it.

Comment: How can you see a database when you cannot connect to PostgreSQL? You have to be **much more** exact to get an answer. We need to see a sequence of commands you typed and the answers you get. Like `ls -la /path/to/tablespace/*` or `psql -U ... -l`, just to suggest a few.

Comment: I am sorry I guess you have got me wrong. I am saying that I am able to connect to PostgreSQL. I am not able to connect to the database inside PostgreSQL. When I connect to PostgreSQL using sudo -u postgres psql postgres, I could connect and when I did \db I could see userdata database. But when I did \c userdata it failed saying that data files is missing.

Comment: `\db` shows tablespaces, not databases. This question is too unclear to answer.

Comment: The question was simply why I am seeing the postgres 9.4.5 tablespaces when I run postgres 9.5 . But when I try to connect to the corresponding database of a tablespace I get error saying missing data file. As I mentioned above the pg_tblspc of postgres 9.5 was pointing to tablespace location of postgres 9.4.5 so that is why I was seeing userdata tablespace in 9.5 as I had never setup userdata database in postgres 9.5 . Thanks a lot for your valuable comments . They helped me gain more clarity

Comment: Then you (or something else) must have run `CREATE TABLESPACE` on the 9.5 installation.